# How to fix TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to learn python from the python crash course but this one task has stumped me and I can’t find an answer to it anywhere

The task is
Think of your favourite mode of transportation and make a list that stores several examples
Use your list to print a series of statements about these items

```
cars = ['rav4'], ['td5'], ['yaris'], ['land rover tdi'] 

print("I like the "+cars[0]+" ...")
```

I’m assuming that this is because I have letters and numbers together, but I don’t know how to produce a result without an error and help would be gratefully received
The error I get is

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str**

Comment: Try this: `cars = ['rav4', 'td5', 'yaris', 'land rover tdi']`

Comment: That’s perfect thank you I know it was a noob question but it really stumped me I am so grateful Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first line actually produces a tuple of lists, hence `cars[0]` is a list.

If you print `cars` you'll see that it looks like this:

```
(['rav4'], ['td5'], ['yaris'], ['land rover tdi'])
```

Get rid of all the square brackets in between and you'll have a single list that you can index into.

Answer (score 9):

```
new_dinner = ['ali','zeshan','raza']
print ('this is old friend', new_dinner)
```

use comma `,` instead of plus `+`

If you use plus sign `+` in `print ('this is old friend' + new_dinner)` statement you will get error.

Comment: this didnt work for me, because im trying to pass it in a function arg.  e.g. `func("string=" , listVar)` `TypeError: takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given` which is kind of expected.  trying to figure out how to do this for a function arg.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the possibilities you can use to get the result needed.
It learns you to import, use the format method and store datatypes in variables and also how to convert different datatypes into the string datatype!
But the main thing you have to do is convert the list or your wished index into a string. By using `str(----)` function. But the problem is that you've created 4 lists, you should only have one!

```
from pprint import pprint
cars = ['rav4'], ['td5'], ['yaris'], ['land rover tdi']
Word = str(cars[0])
pprint("I like the {0} ...".format(Word))
```

Comment: `pprint` is unnecessary and this does not look it outputs in the desired format as OP wished. For ex: this outputs "I like the ['rav4'] ..." where OP wants "I like the rav4 ...".

Answer (score 2):

```
    new_dinner = ['ali','zeshan','raza']
    print ('this is old friend', str(new_dinner))

    #Try turning the list into a strang only
```

Comment: string*********\

Comment: I think the 'strang' is just a comment. Shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: I know this, but I corrected this mistake in a comment, I know that this is not important but it is a spelling mistake

Answer (score 1):

First, create a list (not tuple of lists) of strings and then you can access first element (string) of list.

```
cars = ['rav4', 'td5', 'yaris', 'land rover tdi']
print("I like the "+cars[0]+" ...")
```

The above code outputs: `I like the rav4 ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
new_dinner = ['ali','zeshan','raza']
print ('this is old friend', *new_dinner)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are the answer :

```
cars = (['rav4'], ['td5'], ['yaris'], ['land rover tdi']) 

print("I like the "+cars[0][0]+" ...")
```

What we have done here is calling the list first and then calling the first item in the list.
since you are storing your data in a tuple, this is your solution.